# Import gives a KeyError in Julia

Tags: julia

I want to import **CalculusWithJulia**, I have already added in **Julia 1.5.3**,

```
julia> import CalculusWithJulia
```

when I try to import I get below error

```
Info: Precompiling CalculusWithJulia 
ERROR: LoadError: InitError: KeyError: key :pi not found
```

Comment: I just installed it both using `] add CalculusWithJulia` and `] add https://github.com/jverzani/CalculusWithJulia.jl.git` (master branch from GitHub) in Julia v1.6.0. Importing it with `using CalculusWithJulia` works fine. Try using Julia v1.6.0 and if the error persists, consider submitting an issue on GitHub.